# Extract certain characters from String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have multiple rows in database like below

```
Retractor Color: Blue
Robin Jacket Color: Black (Body) &amp; Red (Stripe)Size: L 
Ladies Clutch in Green   
T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L 
Full Sleeve Sweat Shirt Color: Grey Melange (Light Grey)Size: S 
T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L
Speed Jacket  Size: M
```

I need to extract color and size information for every row into a separate column to identify easily. Since I am not good at regex, can someone please help me how to achieve this.

EDIT:

I need output as below
[image]

Comment: It seemed like `color:` and `size:` were consistent but what is the `Clutch in Green`?

Comment: Green is the color, the string will not have color: consistently

Comment: Maybe you should use `preg_match()`.

Comment: @ PHPglue, I have no idea about using preg_match, can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses a combination of `explode`, `str_replace` and `preg_replace` to do the parsing and has the following features :

- You do not need to define an array with possible options for your colors or sizes. You can use ANY color string and ANY size value
- All rows have three colums.

  - Empty columns have value `NULL`
- You can use both `Color:` and `in` to define your color values

  - For all color values, any `( )` and its content is removed
  - For all color values, `&amp;` is replaced with `,`

---

#### Demo :

https://eval.in/402731

---

#### Code :

```
<?php

$string = "Retractor Color: Blue
Robin Jacket Color: Black (Body) &amp; Red (Stripe)Size: L 
Ladies Clutch in Green   
T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L 
Full Sleeve Sweat Shirt Color: Grey Melange (Light Grey)Size: S 
T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L
Speed Jacket  Size: M";

// Split string on new line character
$data = explode("\n", $string);
$output = [];
// Loop through lines
foreach ($data as $i => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    // Split string on "Color: "
    $data[$i] = explode("Color: ", $value);
    // If color value is not found
    if (count($data[$i]) < 2) {
        // Split string on " in "
        $data[$i] = explode(" in ", $data[$i][0]);
    }
    // If color value is still not found
    if (count($data[$i]) < 2) {
        // Split string on "Size: "
        $data[$i] = explode("Size: ", trim($data[$i][0]));
        //Build output
        $output[$i] = ['Product' => $value, 'Color' => null, 'Size' => $data[$i][1]];
    } else {
        // Split string on "Size: "
        $data[$i] = explode("Size: ", trim($data[$i][1]));
        //Remove " (__) " and replace " &amp ";
        $data[$i][0] = preg_replace('/[ ]?[\(].*[\)][ ]?/U', '', str_replace(' &amp; ', ',', $data[$i][0]));
        // If size value is not found
        if (count($data[$i]) < 2) {
            // Set NULL value for missing Size
            $data[$i][1] = NULL;
        }
        // Build output
        $output[$i] = ['Product' => $value, 'Color' => $data[$i][0], 'Size' => $data[$i][1]];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
?>
```

---

#### Output :

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(21) "Retractor Color: Blue"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
    ["Size"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(58) "Robin Jacket Color: Black (Body) &amp; Red (Stripe)Size: L"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(9) "Black,Red"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "L"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(22) "Ladies Clutch in Green"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(5) "Green"
    ["Size"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(28) "T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(5) "Black"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "L"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(63) "Full Sleeve Sweat Shirt Color: Grey Melange (Light Grey)Size: S"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(12) "Grey Melange"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "S"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(28) "T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L"
    ["Color"]=>
    string(5) "Black"
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "L"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Product"]=>
    string(21) "Speed Jacket  Size: M"
    ["Color"]=>
    NULL
    ["Size"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no consistent formatting and you need to match random color strings, you'll want to have a list of all possible colors. That might be hard if you're calling "melange" a color, which I don't think it is from googling that word. Anyway come up with the colors you can expect, and check if they exist in the string.

Version with color matching in regex.

```
<?php

$colors = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'Blue', 'Grey'];
$colorStr = implode('|', $colors);
$colorPattern = "/({$colorStr})/i";

$sizePattern = '/Size: (\w+)/i';

$rows = [
'Retractor Color: Blue',
'Robin Jacket Color: Black (Body) &amp; Red (Stripe)Size: L',
'Ladies Clutch in Green',
'T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L',
'Full Sleeve Sweat Shirt Color: Grey Melange (Light Grey)Size: S',
'T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L',
'Speed Jacket  Size: M'
];

$output = [];

foreach($rows AS $row){
   $data = ['product'=>$row];

   preg_match($colorPattern, $row, $colorsFound);
   if(isset($colorsFound[1])){
     array_shift($colorsFound);
     $data['colors'] = $colorsFound;
   }

   preg_match($sizePattern, $row, $sizes);
   if(isset($sizes[1])){
      $data['size'] = $sizes[1];
   }
   $output[] = $data;
}

var_dump($output);
```

https://eval.in/402722

(my original version is below, the regex one is better tho.)

```
<?php

$colors = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Black', 'Blue', 'Grey'];

$rows = [
'Retractor Color: Blue',
'Robin Jacket Color: Black (Body) &amp; Red (Stripe)Size: L',
'Ladies Clutch in Green',
'T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L',
'Full Sleeve Sweat Shirt Color: Grey Melange (Light Grey)Size: S',
'T-Shirt  Color: BlackSize: L',
'Speed Jacket  Size: M'
];

$output = [];

foreach($rows AS $row){
   $data = ['product'=>$row];
   foreach($colors AS $color){
      if(stripos($row, $color) !== false){
         $data['colors'][] = $color;
      }
   }
   preg_match('/Size: (\w+)/', $row, $matches);
   if(isset($matches[1])){
      $data['size'] = $matches[1];
   }
   $output[] = $data;
}
```

https://eval.in/402712

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps.

Comment: *"That might be hard if you're calling "melange" a color, which I don't think it is from googling that word."* - "Melange" is french for "mix" ;-) However, the proper spelling is "mélange" with an "é".

Comment: For future iterations if the terms you are searching for will have special characters use `preg_quote`.  Example `$colorPattern = "/(" . preg_quote($colorStr) . ")/i";` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php.

Comment: @AnandaTheerthanJ : The solution provided in this answer is incomplete. My solution is complete and gives you EXACTLY what you want.